# Percentage Formula for Pivot Table

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to calculate the percentage of success for a pivot table in Excel. This is my design:

```
Row Labels  Count   Threshold-%

REG1        224     0.00%
    FALSE   11
    TRUE    213

REG2        213     0.00%
    FALSE   13
    TRUE    200

REG3        318     0.00%
    FALSE   3
    TRUE    315

REG4        467     0.00%
    FALSE   7
    TRUE    460

Grand Total 1222    0.00%
```

And this is my VBA code:

```
Sub CreatePivotTable()

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim pvtCache As PivotCache
Dim pvt As PivotTable
Dim StartPvt As String
Dim SrcData As String
Dim lRow As Long
Dim pf_name As String

    pf_name = "Count of State"

    lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 12).End(xlUp).Row

    'Data Range for Pivot Table
    SrcData = ActiveSheet.Name & "!" & Range("A1:L" & lRow).Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)

    'Set Worksheet
    Set sht = Worksheets("Metrics")

    'Pivot Table Starting Point
    StartPvt = sht.Name & "!" & sht.Range("A3").Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)

    'Create Pivot Cache from Source Data
    Set pvtCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create( _
        SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
        SourceData:=SrcData)

    'Create Pivot Table From Pivot Cache
    Set pvt = pvtCache.CreatePivotTable( _
        TableDestination:=StartPvt, _
        TableName:="PivotTable1")

    Set pvt = Worksheets("Metrics").PivotTables("PivotTable1")

    'Define Rows
    sht.PivotTables("PivotTable1").AddFields RowFields:=Array("Region", "State")

    'Create Count Column
    With pvt.PivotFields("State")
        .Orientation = xlDataField
        .Function = xlCount
        .Position = 1
        .NumberFormat = "0"
    End With

    'Create Calculated Column
    pvt.CalculatedFields.Add Name:="Threshold", Formula:="=SUM(True/True+False)"

    'Populate Calculated Column
    With pvt.PivotFields("Threshold")
        .Orientation = xlDataField
        .Function = xlSum
        .Position = 2
        .NumberFormat = "0.00%"
        .Caption = "Threshold-%"
    End With

    'Show Grand Totals
    pvt.ColumnGrand = True
    pvt.RowGrand = True

End Sub
```

Where I am struggling is creating the formula to execute the design I want. This is the line I have used:

```
'Create Calculated Column
    pvt.CalculatedFields.Add Name:="Threshold", Formula:="=SUM(TRUE/TRUE+FALSE)"
```

All it gives me is 100% for everything. How do I access the TRUE and FALSE values so I can use them in the correct formula?

Also, I only want to display the percentage total (so P% = TRUE/(TRUE + FALSE) * 100) for each Region, without displaying the percentage total for TRUE or FALSE. Then I would like to show the average of region percentages in the Grand Total row, like this:

```
Row Labels  Count   Threshold-%

REG1        224     95.09%
    FALSE   11
    TRUE    213

REG2        213     93.90%
    FALSE   13
    TRUE    200

REG3        318     99.06%
    FALSE   3
    TRUE    315

REG4        467     98.50%
    FALSE   7
    TRUE    460

Grand Total 1222    96.64%
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
pvt.AddDataField pvt.PivotFields("State"), "Threshold", xlCount
With pvt.PivotFields("Threshold")
    .Calculation = xlPercentOfParentRow
    .NumberFormat = "0.00%"
End With
```

Comment: I apologise, my question wasn't as clear as I thought it was. That code worked but only showed me the Count of State total and then the percentage of that total from the Grand Total. What I am trying to work out is the success rate for each region (based on TRUE and FALSE values) and then get the average percentage of those results to show in the Grand Total row

Comment: I have edited the question, to show what I am looking for help with

Comment: I don't know of a way to do that with a pivot table, you'll probably have to use regular formulas, or calc it with VBA

Comment: Would you know how to get access to those values within the pivot table or is this something I would have to calculate separately?